# How to query string used as http host

Tags: .htaccess

I want show below url http://example.com/folder1/

but this url as use http host

and execute url is

http://example.com/?test=folder1

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /?test=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: this is right but I want "http://example.com/folder1/" this url used as a http host when i put echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

it is how http://example.com/folder1

Comment: Didn't understand your comment. `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` will be `example.com`